# Rank of a pair of coprime integers

Tags: number-theory, coprime

Let's say two pairs of coprime integers $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ are connected if $ac + bd = 1$.

A connected chain, or just a chain, is a sequence of coprime pairs in which every two consecutive pairs are connected.

Clearly, if $(a, b)$ is connected to $(c, d)$, then $(a, b)$ is connected to $(c + nb, d - na)$ for an integer $n$.

Using the property, we may find a connected pair $(x, y)$ such that $max(|x|,|y|) < max(|a|,|b|)$.

Continuing the process we may build a chain that ends on $(0, 1)$ or $(1, 0)$ in absolute values.

Examples (in absolute values):

- $(41, 53)$, $(22, 17)$, $(7, 9)$, $(4, 3)$, $(1, 1)$, $(0, 1)$.
- $(41, 53)$, $(31, 24)$, $(7, 9)$, $(4, 3)$, $(1, 1)$, $(0, 1)$.

The described algorithm may give chains of different length:

- $(41, 61)$, $(58, 39)$, $(2, 3)$, $(1, 1)$, $(0, 1)$.
- $(41, 61)$, $(3, 2)$, $(1, 1)$, $(0, 1)$.

Let's define the rank of a pair of coprime integers $(a, b)$ as the minimal length within all possible chains connecting $(a, b)$ with $(0, 1)$ or $(1, 0)$ in absolute values.

Let's call a chain with the minimal length a minimal chain for $(a, b)$.

Questions:

1. Does the rank exist for any pair of coprime or prime integers?
2. Is there a maximal rank within all pairs of coprime or prime integers with rank?
3. Is there an algorithm of constructing a minimal chain or calculating the rank of a given coprime pair?

Comment: not sure what you want.  In  continued fractions, consecutive convergents  are connected.  Anyway, I wrote a gcd thing that replaces the usual "back-substitution"  with the continued fraction   for the ratio of the given positive integers

Comment: @WillJagy Could you explain the connection with continued fractions, please? I am struggling to prove that we can always obtain $(x, y)$ such that $max(|x|, |y|)$ < $min(|a|, |b|)$ or $max(|x|, |y|)$ < $max(|a|, |b|)$.

Comment: Alex, your first chain for (41,53)   are just the convergents for $\frac{53}{41},$   in reverse order.   I put that in an answer. Your second chain for (41,61)  are the convergents for $\frac{61}{41}.$ I suggest that the string of convergents always gives your "rank"  If you have some more examples you have worked, let me know and I will put in the c.f., you may compare

Comment: $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 3 & & 2 & & 2 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 9 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 22 }{ 17 }   & &   \frac{ 53 }{ 41 }  
 \end{array}
 $$

Comment: $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 2 & & 20 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 61 }{ 41 }  
 \end{array}
 $$

Comment: @WillJagy Your suggestion that the rank is equal to the number of steps in the Euclidean algorithm looks right. But can we prove it? Is it possible to derive my $\frac{22}{17}$ from your $\frac{12}{41}$ (or from $\frac{1}{2}$)?

Comment: your $\frac{22}{17}$ is the penultimate convergent for $\frac{53}{41}.$   Perhaps you are looking at the initial string of divisions:  the fractions in the left column are of no importance, those being $\frac{41}{12}, \frac{12}{5}, \frac{5}{2}, \frac{2}{1}. $  Ignore them.  Just look at  $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 3 & & 2 & & 2 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 9 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 22 }{ 17 }   & &   \frac{ 53 }{ 41 }  
 \end{array}
 $$

Comment: @WillJagy Got it! $\frac{53}{41} = [1,3,2,2,2]$, $\frac{22}{17} = [1,3,2,2]$, $\frac{9}{7} = [1,3,2]$, etc. Wow! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question (3), begin with your coprime pair $(a,b)$  with $a > b > 0,$   the minimal chain comes from using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm and writing the (simple) continued fraction for $\frac{a}{b},$ then let each convergent $\frac{p}{q}$   be part of the chain, as pair $(p,q)$

$$  \gcd( 53, 41 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 53 }{ 41 } = 1 +  \frac{ 12 }{ 41 } $$
$$ \frac{ 41 }{ 12 } = 3 +  \frac{ 5 }{ 12 } $$
$$ \frac{ 12 }{ 5 } = 2 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 } $$
$$ \frac{ 5 }{ 2 } = 2 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } $$
$$ \frac{ 2 }{ 1 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$
Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 3 & & 2 & & 2 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 9 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 22 }{ 17 }   & &   \frac{ 53 }{ 41 }  
 \end{array}
 $$
$$  $$
$$ 53 \cdot 17 - 41 \cdot 22 = -1 $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$  \gcd( 61, 41 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 61 }{ 41 } = 1 +  \frac{ 20 }{ 41 } $$
$$ \frac{ 41 }{ 20 } = 2 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 20 } $$
$$ \frac{ 20 }{ 1 } = 20 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$
Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 2 & & 20 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 61 }{ 41 }  
 \end{array}
 $$
$$  $$
$$ 61 \cdot 2 - 41 \cdot 3 = -1 $$

Comment: Your sequence does not agree with his, so you should explain how they are related.  I see no answers above to any of his questions.

Comment: $\frac{53}{41} = [1,3,2,2,2]$, $\frac{22}{17} = [1,3,2,2]$, $\frac{9}{7} = [1,3,2]$, etc.

Comment: The remaining piece is the proof of minimality of the chain obtained this way.

Comment: @AlexC  induction on the length of the continued fraction.